# scp to another linux system via ssh where not using port 22

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy a folder from one system to another using scp (secure copy) however I cannot work out how to specify the port.

I understand that to scp, I can...

```
scp /file/location/folderName user@192.***.*.***:/destination/location/
```

however I have changed the destination system's SSH port so I get get this error...

> ssh: connect to host ***.***.*.*** port 22: Connection refused lost
>   connection

Is there some sort of -p command I can use to specify port number?

I also tried adding the port like this...

```
scp /file/location/folderName user@192.***.*.***:>>portNumHere<</destination/location/
```

---

Updated with solution...

I was struggling not only with using the wrong -P but also where to place. I know understand and this works for me...

```
scp -r -P >>portNumHere<< /file/location/folderName user@192.***.*.***:/destination/location/
```

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question *may* be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se] or [Superuser](http://supuers.com). Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a capital `-P port`.  The lower case `-p` option conflicts with the `-p` "preserve" option from `cp`.

Per [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

```
 scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
     [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
     [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

 ...

 -P port
         Specifies the port to connect to on the remote host.  Note that
         this option is written with a capital ‘P’, because -p is
         already reserved for preserving the times and modes of the
         file.
```

Comment: apologies for not checking man - still learning Linux and it slipped my mind. My other issue which I hadn't made clear was where to position the -P and port but I've worked it out. Thanks for the guidance.